# method of deleting a node from a linked list, incorrect?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

For deleting a node which holds obj and is found in the middle of a linked list I did:

```
traverser -> next() -> retrieve()) == obj
```

where

1. `Single_node<Type>* traverser = head();` initially.
2. `retrieve()` returns the obj stores inside a Single_node
3. `next()` returns the next pointer in a Single_node

This is giving a bad access error on the retrieve()

I don't understand why..?
Are we not allowed to do " xxxxx -> bbbbb -> zzzzz " sort of thing?

Comment: That is definitely allowed assuming that the types are pointers (or something that can have the -> operator done), and that none of the pointers are NULL. Have you tried making sure next() isn't returning NULL?

Comment: Yes, you can do that (I'll leave out the code style talk), so it would seem your error is elsewhere. Source needed to find that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do certainly do it, except when you are pointing at the last element of the list: in this case, `next()` would return `NULL`, and you would see bad access as the result.